# How to support help command-line argument with required arguments in CliBuilder

Tags: groovy, command-line-arguments

I am using the `CliBuilder` to parse command-line arguments for a Groovy script. Among the arguments I have defined, I have one which is mandatory. Is there a way to support a `-h,--help` argument which would print the command usage without the annoying error message about missing arguments?

For example, running the following Groovy script with only the `-h` argument:

```
def cli = new CliBuilder (usage:'test', stopAtNonOption:false)
cli.r (longOpt:'required', required:true, 'Required argument.')
cli.h (longOpt:'help', 'Prints this message')
def options = cli.parse (args)
```

will generate the output below when it gets to the `def options = cli.parse (args)` line, and will automatically stop the script execution:

```
error: Missing required option: r
usage: test
 -h,--help       Prints this message
 -r,--required   Required argument.
```

I would like to display only the usage when the `-h` or `--help` argument is specified, without having to drop the `required:true` option for my required arguments. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may not have understood the question properly, but is

```
cli.usage()
```

what you are looking for?

You can do something like below to avoid it:

```
def options

//or ['-h', '--help'].intersect(args?.toList())
if('-h' in args || '--help' in args) {
    cli.usage() 
} else {
    options = cli.parse (args)
}
```

Comment: Not at all :( When I get to the `cli.parse` method call, if the required argument is missing, the error message (and the usage message) are automatically printed (by the `cli.parse()` method), and the script exits without going to the next line.

Comment: Well in that case you can improvise the logic as updated in the answer. @Laf

Comment: I had hoped I could get away without having to check for the help argument manually. The `intersect` part doesn't work though. If I got it correctly, `['h', '--help']` is a list, so it doesn't have the `intersect` method (which is available for `Map`s).

Comment: [intersect](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#intersect(java.util.Collection)) is available for lists/collections as well. :) It should work. You need to convert the String array `args` to a `list` using `toList()`. use my updated commented code above. Glad it was helpful. @Laf

Comment: @Laf: If I add `println 'here'` after the `def options = cli.parse (args)` line in your original example, `here` still gets printed after the usage message, so it seems that the script does NOT automatically exit.

Comment: `grep` works well here instead of intersect.  `if (args?.grep(['-h', '--help'])) { ...`